# HTTP interceptor causing CORS issue using ionic/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

here i am using ionic for web and mobile also and i am using a https url while integrating it i got cors issues .Later when i checked after removing the **http interceptor** cors issue is resolved but how can i solve this issue below is my code

**issues: While using interceptor i am getting CORS issue and if i remove interceptor it is working fine.**

```
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    token:any;

    constructor(public storage: Storage ) { 
        this.storage.get('Token').then(data => {
            this.token = data;
        });
    }


    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        //Authentication by setting header with token value
        if (this.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: this.token
                }
            });
        }

        if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        }

        request = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
        });

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                   
                }
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.error(error);
                return throwError(error);
            }));
    }


}
```

the request i am getting issue with cors  giving 200 and giving text/html

Comment: I think you need to set more headers. Maybe allowCredentails maybe so special cors header along. Like this it looks a bit barebones.

Comment: tried that also it didnt work

Comment: why dont you just set all the headers at once from the request? something like
 `request.clone({ setHeaders: {...request.headers, {'Authorrization': this.token}}});`

Comment: CORS issue occurs because of a missing response header. The server needs to put it. Please check the logic on server which puts this response header. It most likely requires any specific request header, which you omit with your interceptor somehow.

Comment: @TheFool setHeaders appends the headers to the existing ones.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, isnt this intercepting the request and not the response there? also why would it work without interceptor, if it was generally an issue on the server?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm if  i am removing the interceptor the api call is working only with interceptor it is not working

Comment: @TheFool will try this

Comment: @TheFool I didn't say it is an issue of the server. I said it is set by the server, and they depend most times on request headers. I can't tell which request headers are required on his server to place the response header, he needs to check that. Whatever request header is required on server side, the interceptor most likely removes it.

Comment: I see, makes sense.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm server is aws api gateway and all set to * and except allow credentials turned off

Comment: My guess is that adding the authorization header causes the client to send an OPTIONS request and your server isn't allowing / handling CORS on OPTIONS request. Double check that OPTIONS requests are handled by your gateway properly.

Comment: `* ` is not necessarily accepting localhost. Any chance you try from localhost?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm `*` is all hosts. including `localhost` .. he's using gateway so this is most definitely an improper OPTIONS handler

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm i am using application in web so yes localhost  but still made * so it should run right

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm that's not a real bug, reason the chrome engineers marked it `WontFix` ... just a bunch of devs who don't understand their environment fully

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm please check updated question

Comment: @bryan60 please check updated question

Comment: That screen shot isn't helpful. need your gateway config. ALl this implies server problems.

Comment: @bryan60 problem resolved and the problem occurred from aws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all sounds to me like your issue is that adding the `Authorization` header makes a `GET` request "unsafe" so your client is sending out an `OPTIONS` preflight request prior to the `GET`, and your API gateway isn't configured to handle `OPTIONS` method requests.  You probably need to add a generic `OPTIONS` method handler in your gateway and make sure CORS allows the `OPTIONS` method.

In any event, this issue is almost definitely on the server side and your server config would be needed to provide a detailed explanation of how to fix this.

Comment: As I said, adding the Authorization header makes the request unsafe and thus requires a preflight `OPTIONS` request. Please read the entire answer. I'll bet it works fine if you just don't add the auth header.